# is there an authoritative list of the ways to expound the torah?

Tags: midrash, drush, hermeneutics

We are all familiar with Rebbi Yishmael's 13 principles for expounding the torah, however there are other systems not included in his list. I remember once hearing a shiur that there are over 40 ways to expound the torah. Is there an authoritative list of every way that is used by chazal to expound the torah?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraita_on_the_Thirty-two_Rules

Comment: [tag:parshanut-theory]?

Comment: @DoubleAA, darshanut theory, more like.

Comment: 40? What about Shiv'im Panim?

Comment: @SethJ I think those are ways of understanding the intention/meaning of the torah as opposed to (logical?) methods for expounding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bamidbar Rabba 2:3](http://www.tsel.org/torah/midrashraba/bamidbar.html) explains that there are 49 ways to expound the torah, but does not list them

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you are referring to the famous teaching of Rabbi Eliezer the son of Rabbi Yosi HaGlili that enumerates 32 *middos* (principles) for interpreting the Torah. A detailed discussion of these 32 principles can be found in the back of Tractate Brachos in standard editions of the Vilna Shas, a few pages after the *Mevoh HaTalmud*.